# How to make a username as a foreign key of another model in django

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django. I want to link a model which has 2 field 'username' and 'password'. I want to make 'username' field as a Foreign Key in another model. But in Django we can only pass the whole Model Object, who is referring to as it's foreign key.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What does "make a username field as a Foreign Key" mean? What does "only pass the whole model object" mean (it doesn't sound like any limitation I'm aware of)?

Answer (score 0):

No you can link to any *unique* field of a Django model. So if your models look like:

```
class Target(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class SourceModel(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can assign the value of the target column to the `target_id` then. So for example:

```
Target.objects.create(name='target1')
SourceModel.objects.create(target_id='target1')
```

So you do not need to pass a `Target` object itself. You can use the `…_id` "twin" field to use the target column value. The database will normally enforce referential integrity, and thus will prevent passing a non-existing value to the foreign key column.